# modifying en.yml file for validation error messages rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-i18n

I have never really dealt with or understood the en.yml file as I haven’t used it in the past, today I am trying to change that and customise the validation error messages that are shown when a form submission fails

I have a recipe model, and a form that submits a recipe. At the moment my en.yml file looks like this

```
  en:  
   activerecord:
    models: 
     recipe: 

    attributes:
     user:
      email: 
       errors:
         models:
          recipe:
           attributes:
            dish_name:
             blank: "Dont forget to give your Recipe a Dish Name"
```

Now clearly this is wrong, I was looking for some help on how to layout the file and maybe a explanation on what is going on,ive read the docs but its a little too high level for my skill level when it comes to rails.

Also at the moment if validation fails for dish_name, i.e. its blank I get this error message

```
Dish name Dont forget to give your Recipe a Dish Name
```

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to override the default format for error messages:

```
en:
  errors:
    format: "%{message}"

  activerecord:
    errors:
      models: 
        recipe: 
          attributes:
            dish_name:
              blank: "Dont forget to give your Recipe a Dish Name"
```

Then you should get the desired meessage:

```
Dont forget to give your Recipe a Dish Name
```

Keep in mind this will override the format for other ActiveRecord models as well. Also you need to specify the format for any other locales you will be supporting, otherwise rails will default to showing the attribute.

Comment: ah right, do you know a good resource to explain the format of the .yml file, ie the correct flow? and also if i want to customise say the difficulty attribute would i pecify difficulty: blank:"error message here"  thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes same format for any other attributes. Don't know of any references that deal specifically with the format of the locales yml file, sorry!

Comment: thats ok, now i get can not load translations from /home/richard/recipes/config/locales/en.yml, expected it to return a hash, but does not

Comment: its ok solved it, used YAMLlint to validate, seems yaml cares about whitespace?

Comment: ok this is strange now it has defaulted back to the default message? i havent changed anything, it just worked?